# Let $\epsilon$>0. Let $f$ from $[0, +\infty)$ to $[0, +\infty)$ is differentiable and $f'>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Why is
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f^{1+\epsilon}(x)}{x*f'(x)}=\infty?$$

The L'Hopital rule is not useful here.

Comment: does $f^{1+\epsilon}$ stand for exponent?

Comment: @DonlansDonlans, yes, it is (f(x))^(1+$\epsilon$)

Comment: Presumably the close vote was for not showing his work  so far? But he _did_ evidently try to use L'Hopital...

Comment: Were you asked to prove this or was the problem "prove or give a counterexample"? If the latter you really shouldn't just ask how to prove it... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 4):

This is false as stated (probably it's true with some reasonable additional hypothesis, maybe regarding monotonicity of $f'$).

**The Idea:** We take $f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt$, where $f'>0$ is constructed so that $f'(n)\to\infty$, but $f'$ is very small except at points very close to a positive integer, so that $\int_0^\infty f'\le1$. Then $f(x)\le1$, so the quotient above does  not tend to $\infty$.

**Details:**

Say $h>0$  is a continuous function with $$\int_0^\infty h=1/2.$$ Let $\phi_n\ge0$ be a continuous function such that $\phi_n(n)=4^n$, $\phi_n$ is supported on $[n-1/n,n+1/n]$, and $\int\phi_n=1/2$, and define $$g=h+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\phi_n$$and $$f(x)=\int_0^xg(t)\,dt.$$Then since $g$ is continuous we have $$f'=g\ge h>0.$$But $$0\le f(x)<\int_0^\infty  g=1$$and $$f'(n)>2^{-n}\phi_n(n)=2^n,$$so $$\frac{(f(n))^{1+\epsilon}}{nf'(n)}<\frac1{n2^n}\to0.$$